# Cells Being Cut From Right Side While Generating PDF Using PHPExcel TCPDF

Tags: php, csv, pdf, phpexcel, tcpdf

I am Generating Reports using PHPExcel in CSV and PDF format.

CSV is being generate perfectly but PDF is behaving awkwardly.

Firstly Images are not being shown in PDF. Secondly cells are being cut from right side in PDF.

Here are the screenshots of both.

CSV:
[image]

PDF:
[image]

Here is the code

**To Create PDF Write**

```
$csv = new PHPExcel();    
$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_TCPDF;
$rendererLibrary = 'tcpdf';
$rendererLibraryPath = _LIBRARIES_PATH_."/".$rendererLibrary;
PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer($rendererName,$rendererLibraryPath); 
$csvWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($csv, "PDF");
```

**To Write Image**

```
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Company LOGO');
$objDrawing->setDescription('Company LOGO');
$objDrawing->setPath($companyLogo);
$objDrawing->setWidthAndHeight(150,90);
$objDrawing->setResizeProportional(true);
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('E1');
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($csv->getActiveSheet());
```

**To Write Values**

```
$csv->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A5', 'Sr.');
$csv->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B5', 'User ID');
$csv->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C5', 'Name');
$csv->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D5', 'Total Hrs Worked');
$csv->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E5', 'Total Break Duration');
$csv->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F5', 'Rate/Hr');
$csv->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G5', 'Total Cost');
```

**To Save at the End**

```
$csvWriter->save("php://output");
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using?

Comment: set width for the tcpdf...

Comment: @Stah Updated. Please have a look.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju I am not so familiar with tcpdf. Can you please suggest me a piece of code?

Comment: I'm impressed that the CSV has images and bold text.... never realised that a csv file was even capable of that..... perhaps you should take over development of PHPExcel if you've managed to get a csv file that can do it

Comment: add pdf generation code...

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker i will try to do maybe in near future.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju I am not using any particular code for PDF i am using same code as CSV just creating different writer and saving it with PDF extension.

Comment: then why `tcpdf` is added tags??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Because i am using tcpdf as writer object.